# LinkedIn v2 API: 500 failure when fetching standardized data using projections on multiple organizational entity statistics requests

Tags: linkedin-api

**Problem Description**

Projections for the function and seniority standard data fail with a 500 error code and an unknown reason when fetching data from multiple organizational entity statistics endpoints.

**Problem Scope**

Affected Endpoints

- `/v2/organizationalFollowerStatistics`
- `/v2/organizationPageStatistics`
- `/v2/brandPageStatistics`

Affected Organizational Entities

- Organization
- Organization Brand

Affected Standardized Data

- Functions
- Seniority

**Sample Request**

```
GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:PAGE_ID&projection=(elements*(*, followerCountsByFunction*(*, function~), followerCountsBySeniority*(*, seniority~)))"
```

**Sample Response**

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      followerCountsBySeniority: [
        {
          "followerCounts": {
            "organicFollowerCount": 1,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0
           },
           "function!":{
             "message":"URN Resolution failed for unknown reasons.:com.linkedin.r2.RemoteInvocationException:GatewayException{_serviceErrorCode=null}",
             "status":500
           },
           "function":"urn:li:seniority:2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      followerCountsByFunction: [
        {
          "followerCounts": {
            "organicFollowerCount": 1,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0
           },
           "function!":{
             "message":"URN Resolution failed for unknown reasons.:com.linkedin.r2.RemoteInvocationException:GatewayException{_serviceErrorCode=null}",
             "status":500
           },
           "function":"urn:li:function:2"
         }
       ]
     },
     ...
    ]
}
```

**Additional Information**

- Querying the `/v2/seniority` and `/v2/functions` endpoints using a `GET` request with their respective IDs successfully returns the expected data.
- Projections for other standardized data (e.g. country, region, industry) work as expected.
- Application permission scope granted: `"r_emailaddress r_ads r_basicprofile r_liteprofile r_ads_reporting r_organization_social rw_organization_admin r_1st_connections_size"`